# Javascript dictionary key exists within conditional statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm encountering some strange behavior while working with a dictionary object in Node.JS as part of a MEAN stack project.

I define a `keywordSearches` dictionary earlier in my code, and `searches` is an array of `Search` objects that contains a `keyword` property. I'm essentially pulling from MongoDB a record of all my search requests, and then creating a dictionary containing the frequency of the keyword searches, with the key being the search text, and the value being the frequency of it being searched (an integer). All this is stored in `keywordSearches`.

However, when I use the following code to iterate through my searches, I see the keywords in `keywordSearches` evaluates to false outside of my if condition, but then apparently evaluates to true within the if condition (the very next line!). Why is this occurring?

```
  console.log(keywordSearches);
   for (var i = 0; i < searches.length; i++){
     var keywords =  searches[i].searchBody.keywords;
     console.log(keywords in keywordSearches); // <- this evaluates to false
     if (!keywords in keywordSearches){ // <- this section of code never executes! Why?
       console.log("New keyword found")
       keywordSearches[keywords] = 1; 
     } else {
       keywordSearches[keywords] = keywordSearches[keywords] + 1;
       console.log("else statement")
     }
   }
   console.log(keywordSearches);
```

**Output** (note, I have four `Search` objects, all with keyword "photography":

```
{}  <- console.log(keywordSearches)
false <- (keywords in keyWord Searches)
else statement <- if condition evaluates to false! Should evaluate to true. Why?
true
else statement
true
else statement
true
else statement
true
else statement
{ photography: NaN }
```

I understand why `photography` is `NaN`: it's never initialized with a value of `1`. (which it should if it's initially not found in the dictionary). So it's adding `NaN` + 1 each time.

Comment: this can be an operators precendence issue. try to add parentheses on the if statement doing !(keywords in keywodSearches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` has lower precedence than `!`, so your expression is evaluated as:

```
(!keywords) in keywordSearches
```

Instead of:

```
!(keywords in keywordSearches)
```

See: [Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) on MDN

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `!` completely, and switch the `if-else` statements instead:

```
 console.log(keywordSearches);
 for (var i = 0; i < searches.length; i++){
 var keywords =  searches[i].searchBody.keywords;
 console.log(keywords in keywordSearches); // <- this evaluates to false
 if (keywords in keywordSearches){ 
   keywordSearches[keywords] = keywordSearches[keywords] + 1;
   console.log("keyword already exists")
 } else {
   console.log("New keyword found")
   keywordSearches[keywords] = 1; 
 }
}
console.log(keywordSearches);
```

This saves on an operation.

Comment: This answer lacks why the given code is *not* working. Yes, swapping branches leads to the correct functionality, but as another answer pointed out, the core of the question is about the condition which is not operating as expected.